# Is there any new Text-to-Speech c# library

Tags: c#, wpf, text-to-speech, speech

I was exploring a little, but I did not seem to have found any new Text-to-Speech libraryies that we could use in C#. Did any one of you found something interesting that could be used. I'm looking for a voice that wouldn't sound so robotic or a library that uses some kind of filers.

Did Microsoft maybe update library System.Speech.Synthesis or if they made a new one maybe?

Comment: Which language are you looking for? I am quite impressed with the good quality of the English voices for Windows.

Comment: Microsoft have a revamped TTS as part of their new [Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/) offerings. AFAIK it involves Azure, so won't be entirely free.

Comment: Im looking for English language. It would be good if I could use filters, but not necessary. If would be good that I'd could at least test it for free, before going into production.

Answer (score 0):

One of the new things, is Microsoft Cognitive services. It allows you to add alot of AI features in your project. One of them is text to speech API.

Microsoft Definition :

```
Build apps and services that speak to users naturally. The Text to Speech API — part of Cognitive Services speech services — converts text to audio in near real time, improving accessibility and usability for customers. The API converts text generated by the app into audio that can be played back and saved as a file for later use.

The service speaks to users in multiple languages. Choose from more than 75 voices in over 45 languages or locales, including options for male and female voices, and adjust parameters like speed, pitch, volume, pronunciation, and additional pauses.
```

Here is link : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/

AWS also have their own implementations for AWS Machine learning and they have text-to-speech module if your already using AWS as your infrastrucutre

here is the link : https://aws.amazon.com/polly/what-is-text-to-speech/